# Proving that the two sets are equal.

Tags: analysis

Suppose we claim: $\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [-k, \frac{1}{k}) = [-1, 0]$.

Here is my attempt at proof.

Let us define $A := \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [-k, \frac{1}{k})$ and $B := [-1, 0]$. We prove that $A=B$ by showing that $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$.

To prove that $A \subset B$, let us take an arbitrary element $a \in A$. This means that $a \in [-k, \frac{1}{k'})$ such that $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is the smallest element in $\mathbb{N}$ and $k' \in \mathbb{N}$ is the largest element in $\mathbb{N}$. The smallest element in $\mathbb{N}$ is $1$. Therefore, $a \in [-1, 0]$.

To prove that $B \subset A$, let us take an arbitrary element $b \in B$. We want to show that $b \in [-k, \frac{1}{k'})$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k$ is the smallest element in $\mathbb{N}$ and for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k'$ is the largest element in $\mathbb{N}$. The smallest element in $\mathbb{N}$ is 1. So $b \in [-1, 0]$ since $b \in [-1, 0]$. The proof is complete.

I feel not so good about this proof since I know that there is no largest element in $\mathbb{N}$ to start off.  Please share some ideas to make this proof effective.

Comment: $b \in \bigcap\limits_{k\in \mathbb N} \left[-k, \frac {1}{k}\right)$ means $b\in \left[-k, \frac {1}{k}\right)$, for all $k \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: why are you using $k$ and $k'$? the set is $[-k, \frac{1}{k})$.
$A = \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} ([-k,0) \cup [0,\frac{1}{k}) ) = [-1,0) \cup$ {0} $ = [-1,0]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, there is no largest element in $\Bbb{N}$, besides that's not what the intersection means.

$a\in A$ means that $-k\leq a<\frac1k$ for *ALL* $k\in\Bbb{N}$. If $a\in A$, then $a\geq-1$ because $1\in \Bbb{N}$. Then note that since $a< \frac1k$ for all $k$, then $a\leq 0$. This is true because of (a corollary to) the Archimedian property. I can say more.

The converse is similar. Let $b\in B$, then show that $b\in[-k,\frac1k)$ for each $k$.

Comment: How do we know that $a < \frac{1}{n}, \forall k$ implies $a \leq 0$ by the Archimedean property or the corollary of it? I mean, it could be, since $ka < 1$, which is the opposite of the conclusion of the Archimedean property, so $a \leq 0$. I am not so sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase "the largest element in $\Bbb N$" is problematic.

One kind of argument you could make would use the convergence of the sequence ${\frac 1k}$ to $0$.

The first direction is by contradiction:

Suppose $a \in A$ and $a>0$. Since $a \in A$, $a$ is an element of every interval in the intersection: $a \in \left[-k, \frac{1}{k}\right)$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$.

Since $a>0$ and $\left\{\frac 1n\right\}$ converges to $0$, there exists some $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $a > \frac 1n$. (The convergence tells you that there has to be an element of the sequence that is closer to $0$ than $a$.) But this means that $a \notin \left(-n, \frac 1n\right)$, which is a contradiction because this is one of the intervals in the intersection, and $a$ must be in all of them.

For the converse, suppose that $b \in (-1, 0]$. Then $-1<b\leq 0$.

What you need to show is that for any natural number $k$, $-k<b$. This follows from the fact that for any natural number $k$, $1<k$, so multiplying this inequality by $-1$ you get $-k<-1$. Then putting this one together with the inequality in the previous paragraph, you get $-k<-1<b$.

The other portion, that $b<\frac 1n$, follows from the facts that $\frac 1n>0$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$ and $b$ is negative.

Comment: You don't need convergence. You just need Archimedian property. At this level convergence is overkill.

Comment: Yes, the fact that there is always a $\frac 1n$ closer to $0$ than any positive number would be a corollary to the Archimedean property. I used the convergence mostly as a shortcut; even if OP can't use that fact in the proof, the convergence of that sequence is first seen in calculus, and I think the idea of $\frac 1n$ getting "closer and closer" to $0$ is pretty intuitive, even pictorially.